# What to do when the __name__ shouldn't equal '__main__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I see a lot of people doing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

where main() presumably has all the useful code. What if I don't want the script to be imported?  It doesn't have useful functions/classes to import.  Is it just as elegant to do

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    sys.exit()
    print('this script shouldn\'t be imported')
```

when your code won't do anything for the outsider?

Comment: Shouldn't the outsider be the one to decide whether your module is useful to them?

Comment: Anand, I was thinking this too, but `sys.exit()` does raise a `SystemExit` exception, so outside action is possible: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit .  Sneftel, good point.

Comment: I asked [a related question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/250473/checking-that-a-function-is-only-run-from-main-in-python) on programmers.stackexchange.com and was advised that "the idiomatically correct thing [for Python] is to not care."

Comment: Yep, now I have a deep intuition for why this is the way it is.

Comment: *Why* shouldn't it be imported, and why would you need to *enforce* that? If there's nothing useful for others in there, why do you think they'd be *trying* to import it? And if they *are* trying to import it, doesn't that suggest that your intuition about the usefulness of those classes/functions is inaccurate?

Comment: @jonrsharpe intuition about why I should stick to the convention...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the code simply won't run correctly when it is imported, I would strongly recommend against adding unnecessary safeguards. Don't treat others like children - let them decide. All you need to do is provide documentation about the correct usage.

In the case that someone should import module A instead of B because of some weird order of execution issue, you could raise an exception with a message directing the user to A. But this really isn't a common scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry when your code is being imported, but worry if nobody wants to import it! :)

Indeed What for to protect it in such a way?
If one person has you script it can easily fix it and allow importing.
Best way is to let people decide how to import the code: use as a module or a script.